# Creating null object for input StringReader using JAXBContext

Tags: jaxb, unmarshalling, stringreader

I am trying to create bean from string but unable to create as it is returning null.Here is my code

```
public ModelAndView checkPhotoQualityRequest(
        @RequestBody String photoDataXml, HttpServletRequest request) {
    PhotoQuality photoQuality = null;
    try {
JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext
                .newInstance(PhotoQuality.class);
        Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();
        StringReader reader = new StringReader(photoDataXml);
        photoQuality = (PhotoQuality) unmarshaller.unmarshal(reader);
```

PhotoQuality.java

```
package in.gov.uid.opencvaccess.bean;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessorType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlType;

@XmlType(name = "PhotoQuality")
@XmlRootElement(name = "PhotoQuality")
public class PhotoQuality {


private String photoid;
private byte[] photo;
private boolean quality;
private String message;
public String getMessage() {
    return message;
}
public void setMessage(String message) {
    this.message = message;
}
public String getPhotoid() {
    return photoid;
}
public void setPhotoid(String photoid) {
    this.photoid = photoid;
}
public byte[] getPhoto() {
    return photo;
}
public void setPhoto(byte[] photo) {
    this.photo = photo;
}
public boolean isQuality() {
    return quality;
}
public void setQuality(boolean quality) {
    this.quality = quality;
}
```

}

Please help me to sort out this issue.When I debug and check bean its showing all null values but photoDataXml showing complete xml.

Comment: What does the XML look like that you are trying to unmarshal.  If you populate your object model and then marshal it how does it compare to the XML you are trying to unmarshal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the reason.When I tried using RESTClient its giving null object. But as soon as I written client code and passed StringWriter value created from PhotoQuality Object then it runs properly.